# Informix 4GL report to screen - Reverse

Tags: informix, 4gl

I have a generated report in Informix 4GL that prints to the screen.
I need to have one column displayed in reverse format. 
I tried the following:

```
print line_image attribute(reverse)
```

But that doesn't work. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to the previous answer, you can try the following

```
print "\033[7mHello \033[0mWorld"
```

\033[7m means to print in reverse. And, \033[0m means to go back to standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "is there any way at all to do it", the answer's "yes".  If you mean "is there a nice easy built-in way to do it", the answer's "no".

What you'll need to do is:

1. Determine the character sequence that switches to 'reverse' video — store the characters in a string variable `brv` (begin reverse video; choose your own name if you don't like mine).
2. Determine the character sequence that switches to 'normal' video — store the characters in a string variable `erv` (end reverse video).
3. Arrange for your printing to use:

   ```
   PRINT COLUMN  1, first_lot_of_data,
         COLUMN 37, brv, reverse_data,
         COLUMN 52, erv,
         COLUMN 56, next_lot_of_data
   ```

There'll probably be 3 or 4 characters needed to switch.  Those characters will be counted by the column-counting code in the report.

Different terminal types will have different sequences.  These days, the chances are your not dealing with the huge variety of actual green-screen terminals that were prevalent in the mid-80s, so you may be able to hardwire your findings for the `brv` and `erv` strings.  OTOH, you may have to do some fancy footwork to find the correct sequences for different terminals at runtime.  Shout if you need more information on this.

A simple way which might allow you to discover the relevant sequences is to run a program such as (this hasn't been anywhere near an I4GL compiler — there are probably syntax errors in it):

```
MAIN
    DISPLAY "HI" AT 1,1
    DISPLAY "REVERSE" AT 1,4 ATTRIBUTE(REVERSE)
    DISPLAY "LO" AT 1, 12
    SLEEP 2
END MAIN
```

Compile that into `terminfo.4ge` and run:

```
./terminfo.4ge             # So you know what the screen looks like
./terminfo.4ge > out.file
```

There's a chance that won't use the display attributes.  You'd see that if you run `cat out.file` and don't see the reverse flash up, then we have to work harder.

You could also look at the terminal entry in the `termcap` file or from the `terminfo` entry.  Use `infocmp $TERM` (with the correct terminal type set in the environment variable) and look for the `smso` (enter standout mode) and `rmso` (exit standout mode) capabilities.  Decipher those (I have `rmso=\E[27m` and `smso=\E[7m` for an `xterm-256color` terminal; the `\E` is ASCII ESC or `\033`) and use them in the `brv` and `erv` strings.  Note that `rmso` is 5 characters long.